# Spring Boot Application stuck at INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in [] milliseconds

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, tomcat

I am trying to deploy a Spring Boot application in my local Tomcat server. (It has a very old Spring dependency so it needed to be ran as WAR in Tomcat)

I have excluded spring-boot-starter-tomcat from the pom.xml, and made the neccessary changes inside main class (extended SpringBootServletInitializer etc).
The Applications runs perfectly when i run it from IntellIJ as a Spring Boot App, but when i deploy it in my local environment (packaging war) it does not run at all.

It simply says that Server Startup at ... like the following image:
[image]

Any ideas what might be wrong ? (It doesnt even throw an error at all)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, for this specific error, the version of tomcat played an important role. I checked the Spring Boot Starter Tomcat version which was 8.5.43. The external tomcats on my machine were 9 and 10 (in both it didn't run) so I downloaded Tomcat 8.5.43 version and deployed the war there.

It worked and solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

Your web-app has no error. Check your business logic processing in source code.